# What is an étale covering

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I'm reading Buouville's book: Complex Algebraic Surfaces and in particular i'm interested about the part exposing nice properties of surfaces of general type.
During the lecture i'have found the term étale covering of a surface but on Bouville there's no references about that.
On the web there are lot of different defintions and i need something more precise. Any suggestion about references or some hint about this?

Comment: What is imprecise about, for example, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89tale_morphism? If (like me) you find the long list of equivalent conditions a bit hard to digest, I suggest 5 as the easiest to understand geometrically.

Comment: for examle How would be the definition os an étale cover of a  surface $S$ (that is $S$ complex algebraic projective surface)?

Comment: in my case i don't know the notion af schemes and in my cours of algebraic surfaces the teacher does not used this concept. So i suppose that there is another way to define this cover for example topological way

Comment: One way to say it is: a regular map $X \rightarrow Y$ between complex projective varieties is an etale covering if it is surjective and it is a covering space http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covering_space when we give $X$ and $Y$ the complex topology.

Comment: Does this hold even when $X$ and $Y$ are not smooth?

Comment: So if i take for example the map defined as:

Comment: For complex varieties it is simply the requirement that the derivative be an isomorphism at every point.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding of étale topologies is from a viewpoint of categories, but I believe it will be the same situation for surfaces.

For a topology we need open sets, which is usually a nice natural object.  But if you consider something such as a category, how could you go about defining open sets?

Grothendieck answered this for us, he introduced a whole class of topologies (Grothendieck topologies) and étale topology is one of these.  A Grothendieck topology is given by a function $t$ which assigns to each object $U$ of a category $C$ a collection $t(U)$ consisting of families of morphisms $\{p_i:U_i \to U\}$ for $i$ in some index set such that it satisfies some properties. Then the families in $t(U)$ are called covering families for $U$.

So we can see it as letting the class of morphisms play the role of open sets in analogy to topological spaces.

Now, we have a generic Grothendieck topology, for the étale one we consider étale maps, i.e. flat and unramified maps.  Therefore for the families $\{p_i:U_i \to U\}$ we require $p_i$ to be étale maps!

Comment: so i can say that $C$ is the category of all étale morphism so i can think that the ogject of $C$ are open subset of $X$ respect to étale topology